# Vagrant interactive Ansible provisioning with user input

Tags: ansible, vagrant, gcloud

I was wondering if it was possible to have Vagrant provisioning with Ansible playbooks to have a task where a command which requires user input is executed and pauses to wait for user interaction.

The use case is to auth the gcloud terminal command with `gcloud auth login`. The command asks the user to go to a url which perform the Google authentication and then enter the verification code provided after the access is granted:

```
Go to the following link in your browser:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/....


Enter verification code:
```

I've seen `prompt` and `wait_for` modules for Ansible but it does not look like can be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If the account you're trying to authenticate in that scenario is a service account, give `gcloud auth activate-service-account` a try. It'd be especially useful here because it prompts for nothing, all it does is login a service account using a key file. You can find out more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `expect` module will work on your case. Have you read about it?

Example from ansible docs:

> ```
> - name: Case insensitive password string match
>   expect:
>     command: passwd username
>     responses:
>       (?i)password: "MySekretPa$$word"
>   # you don't want to show passwords in your logs
>   no_log: true
>
> - name: Generic question with multiple different responses
>   expect:
>     command: /path/to/custom/command
>     responses:
>       Question:
>         - response1
>         - response2
>         - response3
> ```

You can combine this with `uri` module to authenticate on google cloud, register the output, parse it with regex or something and then use it on expect module...

Source: [Ansible Expect Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html)